# How to bring in data and aggregate from a separate Google Sheet that is also controlled by a Query Filter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a query filter in a main Google Sheets with some name options such as (All, Adam, Joe, Sarah)

I have another google sheet file with separate sales win/loss data and the sheet name is "Win-Loss" Which shows whether a deal was won or lost and I want to count the number of deals won, deals lost, and the deal win rate

I want the numbers to change based on the name in the dropdown in the main Google Sheet with an "all" option so something like this - (All, Adam, Joe, Sarah), the names in the deals won/lost sheet are in column B and the deal status is in column D. But the names have first and last whereas the dropdown in G1 only has first names.

I'm running into issues where all data is 0 or shows N/A. I've tried various formulas but nothing seems to be doing the trick.

Link to mock main GSheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10FJYa6IsYgaoa1yf2Rd5CItEcjYmXoD1JLvlmpk5dAM/edit#gid=0

Link to mock win-loss GSheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17FhkMrhjKJr1iOcJ4hpCKMwQtd6B_BAyT_XAFt7rIBc/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please share a sample dummy sheet for replication purposes. This way, people in the community will be able to provide you with a proper answer to your problem.

Comment: Where is the data for the win/loss sheet?

Comment: @Tedinoz it's the second Google Sheet linked. I would need to count the number of wins/losses each person had and also calculate the win rate

Comment: It appears you have multiple objectives. Could you specify which of the following tasks you've already accomplished? 
1. Filtering data from the 'Win-Loss' sheet based on the selected name from the dropdown menu in the 'Main Sheet.'
2. Counting the number of deals won and lost for the selected name.
3. Calculating the win rate (deals won / total deals) for the selected name.

Comment: Is this [how you would want the result to look like?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpWDy.gif)?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 the clip you linked is exactly what I'm looking for. I wouldn’t need the list below the stats though. 

I haven't been able to accomplish the 3 objectives you outlined as I've been stuck on figuring our formulas.

Comment: Just for clarification, does the 'Deals' column contain no data?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 you are correct It's mainly the "title" for the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

To aggregate data from the "Win/Loss" spreadsheet file into the "Main Sheet" spreadsheet file, try the following functions:

For the **Won** column:

```
=COUNTIF(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Win/Loss_Sheet_URL", "Win-Loss!A:D"), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 CONTAINS '"&$G1&"'", 0), ""), "*"&$B4&"*")
```

For the **Loss** column:

```
=COUNTIF(IFNA(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("Win/Loss_Sheet_URL", "Win-Loss!A:D"), "SELECT * WHERE Col2 CONTAINS '"&$G1&"'", 0), ""), "*"&$C4&"*")
```

For the **Win/Loss Rate** column:

```
=IFERROR(B5/(B5+C5), "")
```

**Sample Result:**

[image]

These formulas use `COUNTIF` to tally occurrences from the "Win/Loss" sheet based on specified conditions and calculate the Win/Loss rate. Adjust the sheet URL and cell references as needed.

**References**:

These are the modified formulas for aggregating data from "Win/Loss" sheet into "Main Sheet" using Google Sheets functions:

- [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en)
- [IFNA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Use this `QUERY` formula in cellA6 of sheet "stats" of spreadsheet "StackOverflow Mock - Main Sheet":

`=query({IMPORTRANGE(A1,A2)},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where Col1 is not null "&IF(G1<>"All","and Col2 contains '"&G1&"'",),1)`

where:

- Cell A1 = `url` of "StackOverflow Mock - Win/Loss Sheet"
- Cell A2 = `Win-Loss!A1:D`; the range to import.

Calculate the Win/Loss and Win-Loss ratio separately.

---

**SAMPLE - ALL**

[image: all]

**SAMPLE-ADAM**

[image: adam]